# renameTo() method deleted my files but where did the files go?

Tags: java, file, groovy, filesystems

this is my code its really simple:

```
def dir = "C:\\Test"

def folder = new File(dir)

def files


folder.setReadable(true)

folder.eachFileRecurse { file ->
    file.renameTo(file.name.replace("_", ""))
}
```

I realize now that renameTo wants the absolute file path, not just the file name, but I ran my code by mistake and now the files are gone. I assume that the files have been moved... somewhere but I have no idea where to look. or are the files gone?

here is an example file name:
`arsenicgreenwalls_merged.package`

Comment: I should add that my hard drive is now full so I don't think the files are gone, I think they have been moved but if they are not under the C:/ or D:/ dir where could they be??

Comment: Oh wow, I think you renamed them all to empty String. I have no idea what that would actually do. The very last one *might* still be somewhere.

Comment: No. I think they are all still on my drive. its a small solid state, and I copied the files onto it before doing this test. after this test failed I deleted the folders that were still remaining and tried to re-copy the files to have another test, but my hard drive was full.

Comment: In the current working directory that you were in when you ran the java code

Comment: Thank you. I now see them all in my project view. I am a dummy :)

Comment: `java.io.File#getName` only returns the name component of the file, not the oath, so, it’s entirely possible for it to have been moved to the current working directory, from which the program was executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at the working directory (current directory) - when you ran this file.